# Nothing works on when full-screen is initialized on any element

Tags: html5-fullscreen

I am working on a WordPress website and I have got a YouTube video where the full-screen isn't working. On the `iframe` `allowfulscreen='true'` is set and when you click on the full-screen icon it does initialize something, however the original body is visible and not the youtube video or in other words its `iframe`. Upon inspecting the `iframe` it looks like the it has covered the page though the video isn't visible.

I tried setting the `z-index` value and `opacity` values to make sure that it wasn't an issue with the CSS, however just as a test I made a random element full-screen using `$0.webkitRequestFullScreen` the same problem occured. Any idea what can be the possible cause?

Comment: Provide the code so far you have

Comment: It's a WordPress site, you can check the URL here - https://codifydtest.com/content-syndication-platform/

Comment: And what's your backend plugin? I suggest you to use `fancybox` when doing this kind of things in wordpress. Easy configuration

Comment: It's a problem with the browser's native fullscreen